# Referring to base class property from a derived template specialization function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Let's say we have a base class that does nothing but contain other values and performs certain operations on them, such as printing them:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
    public:
        Base (const T& t) : value(t) {}
        void printValue () {
            cout << value << endl;
        }

    protected:
        T value;
};
```

Then let's say we want to derive from this template class to provide additional functionality. For the sake of this discussion, I'll keep it simple and just say we're adding the ability to change the contained object's value. Setting `value = t` will not work in derived template functions, but qualifying the value with `this->` will:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T> {
    public:
        Derived (const T& t) : Base<T>(t) {}

        void setValue (const T& t) {
            this->value = t;
        }
};
```

But now, let's say I want to specialize a function for certain types of instantiated objects. Say, if a type can be incremented, like int, I want to provide that functionality:

```
template <>
class Derived<int> {
    public:
        void increment () {
            this->value++;
        }
};
```

This does not work, because the compiler will not recognize the base class' property `value`. I've also tried inserting a `using Base<int>::value` declaration before the increment, and it still doesn't work (at least, not with g++). I get a compiler error `‘Base<int>’ is not a namespace`

Is there a way to refer to base template class' properties from a specialized template function? Using `this->` works for derived template classes, but not for specialized functions for derived classes. I've also found that puting `using Base<T>::value` in `Derived::setValue` rather than using `this->` doesn't work, although I thought it should. Any thoughts?

**Update:** This is the complete code:

```
    template <typename T>
    class Base {
        public:
            Base (const T& t) : value(t) {}
            void printValue () {
                cout << value << endl;
            }

        protected:
            T value;
    };

    template <typename T>
    class Derived: public Base<T> {
        public:
            Derived (const T& t) : Base<T>(t) {}

            void setValue (const T& t) {
                this->value = t;
            }
    };

    template <>
    class Derived<int>: public Base<int> {
        public:
            void increment () {
                //using Base<int>::value;
                this->value++;
            }
    };
```

And these are the errors:

```
templatebase.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
templatebase.cpp:36:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived<int>::Derived(int)’
templatebase.cpp:36:21: note: candidates are:
templatebase.cpp:27:7: note: constexpr Derived<int>::Derived(const Derived<int>&)
templatebase.cpp:27:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Derived<int>&’
templatebase.cpp:27:7: note: constexpr Derived<int>::Derived(Derived<int>&&)
templatebase.cpp:27:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Derived<int>&&’
```

Comment: Your `Derived<int>` does not inherit from any `Base`. You can explicitly specialize a single member function without specializing the class template itself, IIRC it's `template<> void Derived<int>::increment { ++value; }`

Comment: Yeah I also tried putting `: public Base<int>` after `class Derived<int>` but that still didn't work.

Comment: If you want the specialization to derive from `Base<int>` you need yo say so explicitly: `template <> class Derived<int> : public Base<int>`. Don't "try" to put it there, just put it there and leave it there. Update your post accordingly. Do include the exact compiler errors you are getting.

Comment: Works for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/691767138ac466a2 Note you're also missing the call to `Base<int>`'s non-default ctor.

Comment: By the way, as written, the specialization is not needed. Adding `increment` to the main template achieves more for less.

Comment: @dyp: That did it, thanks. I didn't realize that the entire specialized class needed to be defined again.

Comment: Again, ig you want the specialization to have a non-default constructor, you need to add one. A specialization is not an incremental update to the main template, it is a totally separate, unrelated template.